# Call function from within Bash for-loop and capture output?

Tags: bash, for-loop, curl

I've written a Bash script

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash 
SEVEN_DAYS="$((1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7))"
TODAY=$(($(gdate +'%s * 1000 + %N / 1000000')))
PAST_WEEK=$(($TODAY - $SEVEN_DAYS))

get-stuff() {
    stuff=$(curl -s localhost:8888/path/to/data | jq --raw-output '[.time_series_by_stuff[].counts | keys | .[]] | unique | sort | .[]')
    echo $stuff
    }

get-last-weeks-events-by-stuff() {
    for stuff in $(get-stuff); do
    result=$(curl -s localhost:8888/path/to/$stuff/_search -d "{\"query\":\"range\":{\"ingestDate\":{ \"gte\":$PAST_WEEK}}}" | jq 'hits.total')
    echo $stuff
    echo $result
    done
}
```

When executed by itself on the command-line `get-stuff` will echo the values i need eg `foo`,`bar`,`baz`.

How can I capture each of those values so they can be expanded correctly in the curl command within `get-last-weeks-events-by-stuff`?

Should i create a tmp variable like

```
get-last-weeks-events-by-stuff() {
        for stuff in $(get-stuff); do
        tmp=$stuff
        result=$(curl -s localhost:8888/path/to/$tmp ...
```

Ultimately when I call `get-last-weeks-events-by-stuff` it should produce output like

`foo`
`12`
`bar`
15

Comment: Your style is weird. In `get-stuff`, you don't need the variable `stuff` and the `echo $stuff`. The `curl ... | jq ...` is enough—unless you rely on pathname expansion, but I doubt it. Also, a hyphen in a function name is… weird too. Don't do this.

Comment: Is the loop iterating through all values returned by `get-stuff`? Running the script as `bash -x <script>` might help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the IFS environment variable to split on a `,` instead of whitespace.

```
get-last-weeks-events-by-stuff() {
  IFS=,
  for stuff in $(get-stuff); do
    result=$(curl -s localhost:8888/path/to/$stuff/_search -d "{\"query\":\"range\":{\"ingestDate\":{ \"gte\":$PAST_WEEK}}}" | jq 'hits.total')
    echo $stuff
    echo $result
  done
  unset IFS
}
```

According to the [Linux Documentation Project](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/internalvariables.html)

```
$IFS

    internal field separator

    This variable determines how Bash recognizes fields, or word boundaries, when it interprets character strings.

    $IFS defaults to whitespace (space, tab, and newline), but may be changed, for example, to parse a comma-separated data file. Note that $* uses the first character held in $IFS. See Example 5-1.
```

Hope this helps.